# How the if statements works in spring service?

Tags: spring

So a user will be able to login by username or email. So before access to dao layer, I want to check the type of the user login first with the code below:

```
public UserAccount validateLogin(String loginName, String password) {
    logger.info("Validate login account");
    UserAccount aUser = new UserAccount();
    // Login by username and password
    if( aUser.validateUsername(loginName) && aUser.validatePassword(password)) {
        System.out.println("Login with username");
        return userDao.validateByName(loginName, password);
    } 
    // Login by email and password
    if( aUser.validateEmail(loginName) && aUser.validatePassword(password)) {
        System.out.println("Login with email");
        return userDao.validateByEmail(loginName, password);
    } 
    // Fail validation.
    System.out.println("Fail Login Validation");
    return null;
}
```

Case1: If I try to login with valid username and password, it processes find. But if I try to login with valid email and password, it doesn't go through the second if.
Case2: If I switch the order of the if statements, then this time, I can login by email but not by username.

Isn't it weird? So I try to debug it with the code below with a flag:

```
public UserAccount validateLogin(String loginName, String password) {
    logger.info("Validate login account");
    UserAccount aUser = new UserAccount();
    int check = 0;
    System.out.println("level 1");
    if( aUser.validateEmail(loginName) && aUser.validatePassword(password)) {
        System.out.println("Login with email");
        check = 1;
    } 
    System.out.println("level 2");
    if( aUser.validateUsername(loginName) && aUser.validatePassword(password)) {
        System.out.println("Login with username");
        check = 2;
    } 

    System.out.println("check lvl 1: " + check);
    if(check == 1 ) {
        return userDao.validateByEmail(loginName, password);    
    }
    System.out.println("check lvl 2: " + check);
    if( check == 2 ) {
        return userDao.validateByName(loginName, password);
    }   
    // Fail validation.
    return null;    
}
```

This time, the console stop printting after output "level 2" when I try to login with username. I expected that I would at least print out "login with usename". I have no clue where the bug would be.

Should I handle the validation in the controller class?

Validate username:

```
public boolean validateUsername(String username) {
    boolean isValid_flag = false;

    boolean nameHasContent = ( username != null ) && ( !username.equals(""))
                                && ( username.length() > MIN_LENGTH )
                                && ( username.length() < MAX_LENGTH );

    // Invalid user-name's minimum requirements.
    if( !nameHasContent ) {     
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid username" );
    } 

    // Iterate the String to validate each character.
    StringCharacterIterator iterator = new StringCharacterIterator( username );
    char aChar = iterator.current();            // Get the current character.

    while( aChar != StringCharacterIterator.DONE ) {
        isValid_flag = ( Character.isLetter( aChar ) || Character.isDigit( aChar ));

        if( !isValid_flag ) {
            String err_msg = "Username can contain only (a-zA-Z0-9)";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( err_msg );
        }
        aChar = iterator.next();                // Get the next character.
    }
    return isValid_flag;
}
```

Validate email:

```
public boolean validateEmail( String email ) {
    boolean isValid_flag = false;

    EmailValidator emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
    isValid_flag = emailValidator.isValid( email );
    if( !isValid_flag) {
        String err_msg = "Email is not valid format.";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( err_msg );
    }
    return isValid_flag;
}
```

Validate password:

```
public boolean validatePassword(String password) {
    boolean isValid_flag = false;
    boolean passwordHasContent = (( password != null ) 
                                && ( !password.equals(""))
                                && ( password.length() > PWD_MIN_LENGTH )
                                && ( password.length() < PWD_MAX_LENGTH ));

    // Invalid password's minimum requirements.
    if( !passwordHasContent ) {     
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid password" );
    } 

    // Iterate the String to validate each character.
    StringCharacterIterator iterator = new StringCharacterIterator( password );
    char aChar = iterator.current();            // Get the current character.

    while( aChar != StringCharacterIterator.DONE ) {
        isValid_flag = ( Character.isLetter( aChar ) 
                        || Character.isDigit( aChar ));

        if( !isValid_flag ) {
            String err_msg = "Password can contain only (a-zA-Z0-9)";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( err_msg );
        }
        aChar = iterator.next();                // Get the next character.
    }
    return isValid_flag;
}
```

Comment: can u provide your validate methods..?

Comment: Terry why don't you use Spring Security with custom UserService? So much quicker and lot less pain.

Comment: @sasi: I dont think the validate methods wrong because I have check it by switching the if statement as I mentioned above. Even if my validate methods are all wrong, the console would still be able to print out the the third System.out.println (I expected).

Comment: @Aeseir: I want to learn Spring Security but I am having trouble to configure the xml file. But anyway, this is simple validation so I didnt think it would have this kind of problem

Comment: Don't have to do XML, use JavaConfig. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc. Just implement it as they have it listed. 5 min job. Otherwise you are cheating yourself out of valuable knowledge.

Comment: Thank for the link. I understand the benefit of using spring security and I definitely learn to use it after I finish hibernate and spring mvc.

Comment: If you really don't want to go down this path then you need to provide the code for validatingEmail, validatingUsername & validatingPassword